# hash method in Ruby not returning the object_id

Tags: ruby

I'm learning Ruby. I've got the O'Reilly book, "The Ruby Programming Language," which states unequivocally:

"Object class implements the hash method to simply return an object’s ID."

I've also seen this assertion in other books: http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/web-development/ruby/9780321700308/create-classes-that-understand-equality/ch12lev1sec8

But when I run this code, the two lines do not generate the same number:

```
myObject = Object.new

puts myObject.hash
puts myObject.object_id
```

So what's the deal? I'm running Ruby 1.9.3.

Comment: I guess the resources are assuming a wrong version are are using outdated information ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Object implementation hashes the `object_id`. The value isn't the `object_id`, but the `object_id` is the input to the hash function.

Via https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/object.c#L110

```
VALUE
rb_obj_hash(VALUE obj)
{
    VALUE oid = rb_obj_id(obj);
    st_index_t h = rb_hash_end(rb_hash_start(NUM2LONG(oid)));
    return LONG2FIX(h);
}
```

Comment: Neither, just poorly phrased. I think the intent of what the book says is "the input to the hash is simply the object_id". By contrast, the input an object hash for another class might be the concatenation of its values, or some other value guaranteed to be unique in the class.

Answer (score 1):

#### object_id → fixnum

**Returns** an integer identifier for obj. The same number will be returned on all calls to id for a given object, and no two active objects will share an id.

#### hash()

**Generates** a Fixnum hash value for this object. This function must have the property that a.eql?(b) implies a.hash == b.hash. The hash value is used by class Hash. Any hash value that exceeds the capacity of a Fixnum will be truncated before being used.

Resuming: integer identifier is not generated hash.

- http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-hash
- http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-object_id

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby `object_id` is an instance method of `Object`.

[image]

`hash` is also an instance method of `Object`, but it has been re-writed in each subclasses. 
like `String`:

[image]

There has no evidence to show that `hash` should return the save value as `object_id`. They are created for difference purposes.